# Toshiba P755 S5260 Keyboard LED backlight won't light up

Tags: keyboard

I have a Toshiba Satellite p755-s5260 with the LED backlit keyboard with shortcut keys above the keyboard that are also supposed to light up. The LED's are enabled in the BIOS and work up until Ubuntu boots up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you take a look at this question - [How to light up backlit keyboard?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13886/how-to-light-up-back-lit-keyboard)

Answer (score 3):

Basically use `xset` to toggle the state of the led backlight. A little script and your set.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /tmp/keyboard_light ]; then
xset -led 3 && rm /tmp/keyboard_light
else
xset led 3 && touch /tmp/keyboard_light
fi
```

or use "key touch" [Download Here](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/download.php)

This can configure ALL your special keys.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a toshiba satellite s5265, with the same issues as you and this is how I managed to make my keyboard light up:
I booted up a windows install dvd and on the install screen, i pressed the backlight key on top of the keyboard (looks like a square with an arrow inside) just once.
When I rebooted, the keyboard backlight stayed on throughout. Hopefully this will help you and others.

I will be ready to answer any questions you have

Comment: This is the only answer that really worked. After that, it's still not possible to change keyboard backlight behavior through FN key or multimedia key or shell commands, only through BIOS, but I give a +1 to this as a working workaround. If anyone can find a solution to make FN key works, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put any disks in at all.
Just press the backlight key on top of the keyboard (looks like a square with an arrow inside) just once.
It is above F9.
It should work.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for participating in askubuntu! Please refer to the guidelines at http://askubuntu.com/help/behavior It is requested that users not use signatures.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is a Toshiba p745 and I dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows. My keyboard backlight does not work when I boot Ubuntu. However, I can suddenly make it work when I log on to Windows in safe mode and shutdown immediately.

Comment: Please ask your own question, this one is from 2011 and this is a Q&A site not a forum, this space is for answers.

Comment: @markkirby: This *is* an actual answer!  (read again: only works for dual-boot and **not very clear, but it *is* an answer!**)  **;-)**