# Enable the keyboard backlights on supported Lenovo (e.g. Carbon X1) with command

Tags: command-line, 13.10, keyboard, lenovo, backlight

Some Lenovo laptops have keyboard backlights, and they can be turned on using `Fn` + `Space`. There are three states: off, normal and bright.

When I start Ubuntu, these laptops always default back to a burning sun screen brightness and the keyboard lights off.

I want a medium brightness and keyboard lights on by default, because I usually use this laptop in dark environments.

The backlight is easy. Internet is filled with information about this.
`echo 10 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

But how do I turn on the keyboard backlights with a command?
I've been looking here but it seems to do nothing:
`/sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight`

---

### Updates

I tried `for i in {1..32}; do xset led $i; done` but nothing changes. Perhaps the keyboard backlight for Lenovo laptops has a proprietary driver and can only be controlled through `tpacpi`?

Also tried `for i in $(find /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/ | grep /brightness\); do echo 255 > $i; done` of no avail.

Comment: Either `xset led` *(that is almost 100% likely to be Caps Lock, etc, but I'll add it in anyway)* or [`setleds`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/setleds.1.html). **Edit:** Found [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13886/how-to-light-up-back-lit-keyboard)

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried `for i in {1..32}; do xset led $i; done` but nothing changes.

Comment: Thank you for the Fn-space combo since I could not figure it out for quite some time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks as this has been updated, my X1C with ubuntuMATE 16.04 LTS has

```
/sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

which works as expected ie:

```
# echo 2 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Brings it to full light :)

Comment: Hey, yes indeed! Thanks for taking the time to share this to an old question. :)

Comment: No probs, it was the first hit when I was looking, thought it can't be _that_ hard, so thought I should update this one with my findings :)

Answer (score 18):

This is really needed to be fixed!

I think this is a common bug in new thinkpads. If you light keyboard manually `fn + space` then executed:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight/brightness
```

keyboard will fade out.
Please see the following link if it helps:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/ibm-acpi-devel/msg03090.html

Comment: Hey you're right, I didn't know. Since we can turn it off, it 'feels' like it would be a piece of cake to fix this for developers. Is there a bugreport yet?

Comment: The email suggested this workaround:
https://gist.github.com/hadess/6847281 Any idea how can we implement it ?

Comment: Note the "thinklight" is different to the keyboard backlight.  Mine does not have a thinklight.

Answer (score 5):

This is the bash script I use:

https://gist.github.com/vzaliva/0adba7bc40e2f31a0b5f802af2a63267

Works on IBM ThinkPad X260 with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: IBM? That laptop has got to be at least 10 years old! But it works on my Carbon X1, too! To be fair, the code from __hadess__ as answered by __rashad__ did the same, but I don't want to take 5 steps and install compilers. I was looking for a simple bash command. And this is something I can use. Thank you for responding to my 3 year old question. Accepted.

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Of course I have meant Lenovo Thinkpad and my X260 is brand new.  I just had the same problem and found this answer, but I did not like C program which also requires manual modprobe, so I re-wrote it as a script. The original C program authors did all heavy-lifting.

Comment: Thank you. Works in 2022 just as good :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it works fine with me with this gist:

https://gist.github.com/hadess/6847281

- First of all download the gist above, I renamed it to `ThinkLight.c` instead of `tmp.c`.
- Make sure you have glib-2.0 installed:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
  ```
- Compile `ThinkLight.c` as the following:

  ```
  gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include ThinkLight.c -o ThinkLight -lglib-2.0
  ```
- Load `ec_sys` module ( this can be added to `/etc/modules` on boot ):

  ```
  sudo modprobe ec_sys
  ```
- Finally execute `ThinkLight` with level argument (0, 1, or 2):

  ```
   sudo ./ThinkLight 0
   sudo ./ThinkLight 1
   sudo ./ThinkLight 2
  ```

Special thanks to [hadess](https://github.com/hadess) for making this happen!

Comment: Any idea how to run this without sudo? Trying to run this within another script, and that runs as my user.

Comment: I tried this and got some errors :(                                                                                                   ThinkLight.c: In function ‘main’:
ThinkLight.c:56:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘lseek’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (lseek (fd, 0xd, SEEK_CUR) < 0) {
      ^~~~~
ThinkLight.c:60:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘write’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (write (fd, &levels[level], 1) < 0) {
      ^~~~~

Comment: @HeribertoJuarez this is an old answer, you can manipulate this directly with the new Linux kernels. Check wuxmedia's answer

Answer (score 1):

My T450s would not re-enable keyboard backlight upon resume with kernels older then 4.6. FWIW, with 4.6 now, keyboard backlight is set to the brightness it had before suspend.