# how could i turn on backlight keyboard on Lenovo T450s

Tags: lubuntu, lenovo, keyboard-backlight

i'm hoping somebody could help me. I was trying to turn on my backlight laptop keyboard on lenovo T450s ubuntu 16 LTS, i had googling with nothings found,i tried FN+space and xset led 3.. please Help, Open source Teams

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable the keyboard backlights on supported Lenovo (e.g. Carbon X1) with command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/383501/enable-the-keyboard-backlights-on-supported-lenovo-e-g-carbon-x1-with-command)

Answer (score 0):

I got this from wuxmedia in another post for a t520,but it also works for my t450. Enjoy!

## echo 2 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness

Brings it to full light :)