# Lenovo Yoga C740 Keyboard back light

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, hardware, backlight

I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on my new Lenovo Yoga C740. The keyboard back light is not working to light up the keys.

Comment: Try _echo 2 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness_ with thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/885114/how-could-i-turn-on-backlight-keyboard-on-lenovo-t450s

Answer (score 1):

From the following link: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/pr/en/solutions/ht104656

"To turn on or off the backlight, press Fn + Spacebar or Esc on the keyboard to change the keyboard backlight mode. There are three modes: Off, Low (dim), and High (bright). Press the keys again to change the modes.

The backlight keyboard feature is a physical switch and does not require driver support."