# cannot turn on keyboard backlight

Tags: 14.04, asus, keyboard-backlight

I am using ASUS UX303 LN, Laptop and Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 is installed on it. I cant find a way to turn on my keyboard backlight on it. The keyboard shortcut that works in windows is not working here. Please help

Comment: you must check the layout of your keyboard and change it to what fits your needs

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To enable the backlight:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

The `2` at `echo 2 |` can be changed to a value between 0 - 3, with 3 being the brightest.

To disable the backlight, enter:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

The path may vary depending on laptop model and your OS. For example Lenovo Thinkpad L390 running Manjaro has `/sys/class/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness`. You can use `find` to see the correct path:

```
find /sys/class/leds -name '*kbd_backlight'
```

Comment: It works when i type in, but when I add it as a custom keyboard shortcut its not working

Comment: Why turning on keyboard backlight needs administrative permission？

Comment: @funicorn because you are changing hardware features

Comment: echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness
echo 3 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness
Thinkpad...

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
xset led on
```

or

```
xset led 3
```

This worked well with my CMSTORM (Cooler Master Storm Devastator) keyboard.

Comment: This worked for me. Plus, an easier way to apply this command at start up is to use  Ubuntu's Startup Application and just and this command there. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 5):

You can turn on backlight by this command

```
sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness <<< 3
```

This will set it to maximum. The number at the end means brightness ( 0 - 3).

You can link this command to some hot key combination.

You can also read [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Zenbook_Prime_UX31A#Ambient_Light_Sensor_.28ALS.29) regarding setting up Ambient Light Sensor.

Comment: It works when i type in, but when I add it as a custom keyboard shortcut its not working

Comment: This is actually another topic how to setup a script requiring sudo to a key combination. It must be answered already somewhere. I make a script and set that it does not require a password in sudoers.

Comment: Works for live tech ergonomic keyboard as well.

Comment: This gives me `tee: '/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness': No such file or directory 3`. Anything else I can try?

Comment: This means that there is no backlight, or it is not supported.

Comment: @Pilot6 When booting, the backlight is off and I haven't figured out a way to turn it on. I have tried all suggestions here. The strange part is: it comes automatically on to the brightest setting when the computer resumes from suspend.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I got it solved:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Adjust the keyboard backlight level

shopt -s -o nounset

declare -i KBD_BACKLIGHT_MAX=`cat /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight/max_brightness`
declare -i KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV=`cat /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness` 

# We need a parameter, etiher inc or dec
if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
   exit 192
fi 

case $1 in
-inc ) 
   # increasing:
   if [ ${KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV} -lt ${KBD_BACKLIGHT_MAX}  ] ; then
      KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV=${KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV}+1
      echo ${KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV} | tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
   fi
   ;;
-dec )
   # decreasing:
   if [ ${KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV} -gt 0 ] ; then
      KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV=${KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV}-1
      echo ${KBD_BACKLIGHT_LEV} | tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
   fi
   ;;
esac

exit 192
```

Save the above script in /opt/tweaks/kbd_backlight_adjust.

Then this needs to be run with sudo from a keyboard shortcut so we must add a line to sudoers.

Use visudo and add this line to the bottom:

```
your_username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /opt/tweaks/kbd_backlight_adjust
```

And finally create your keyboard shortcuts using these commands for increasing and decreasing the keyboard backlight:

```
sudo /opt/tweaks/kbd_backlight_adjust -inc
```

and

```
sudo /opt/tweaks/kbd_backlight_adjust -dec
```

That should do it :-)

Comment: excelent ! just missing the command chmod +x /opt/tweaks/kbd_backlight_adjust to enable of script execution.

Comment: Thank you for this script. It worked fine for me and solved my problem.Running Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Yoga Gen4

Comment: What if I have no `opt/tweaks` directory?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with an Asus ROG laptop I'd purchased. Here's what I did to fix keyboard shortcuts in general.

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

You’ll find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Simply add on to the end of it:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Save, Exit and Reboot

Comment: This is not working for me on an ASUS ROG G401IU with Ubuntu 20.04. I tried with both `acpi_osi=`, `acpi_osi=linux` with and without `acpi_backlight=vendor`. When I reboot the computer, the keyboard backlight is off again.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily update kernel using "Ukku Kernel Update Utility" https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu Updates to 5.x kernel solve all my problem on Asus UX433F (backlight, sound).