# Does Ubuntu run on an Asus F555LA

Tags: laptop, asus

Does anyone have any experience with an Asus F555LA-DM2095T laptop? I'm looking for a new laptop and I'm thinking of buying this one but I'm not sure if it'll run properly.
I've read a review on a similar model (ASUS F555LA-AB31) that does seem to work. I think the only difference between the two is the hard-drive (HDD over an SSD) and the processor (i3 over an i5).

I'm specifically asking if this hardware will run Ubuntu because I can not find any review on this model.

I'd really like to know if anyone has ever tried to run Ubuntu on this laptop.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for hardware-recommendations.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543006 @Audax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall it should run fine.

I have an Asus UX303LA with quite similar specs and the things I had to tweak to make them work were the hotkeys for the display brightness and the keyboard back light (see this link for a workaround for the keyboard backlight issue if you experience it: https://askubuntu.com/a/701145/474849).

The gestures on the touch pad might also need some tweaking...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and te related article. I'll be sure to try it out when I get it.

Answer (score 0):

The main issues with Ubuntu tend to be with wireless cards and Nvidia or AMD graphics cards. Since the Asus F555LA-AB31 got good reviews, and the only differences in the models are HDD and processor (components which are generally very well-supported under Linux), I'd say go for it!