# How to make my Toshiba u940 laptop's keyboard backlit to work?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, backlight, toshiba

I am using the latest Xubuntu x64 version as of this posting.. It's installed in dual boot with Windows 10.. the KB Backlight is working when I boot on Windows and from the bios.. The moment It enters the Xubuntu Startup screen the KB Backlight turns off and doesn't turn on.. Thanks in advance for the help..

**Output of**: `ls /sys/class/leds/`

```
input3::capslock 
input3::numlock 
input3::scrolllock 
phy0-led
```

Comment: check this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/644420/464430

Comment: Thanks @MohamedSlama for the quick response but that one's for Asus..

Comment: Isn't it just `xset led 3` to turn it on, and `xset -led 3` to turn it off?

Comment: Hi @Terrance, tried it but it does not work..

Answer (score 3):

To enable the backlight:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/toshiba::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

The `2` at `echo 2 |` can be changed to a value between 0 - 3, with 3 being the brightest.

To disable the backlight, enter:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/toshiba::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

reference this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/644420/464430)  but changing **asus**  to **toshiba** .

***Updated***

some people whom report this issue say disabling `acpi` solve the problem to disable `acpi`:

1. open terminal
2. edit `/etc/default/grub`
3. append `acpi = off` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
4. `update-grub`
5. if not working do these steps again and delete `acpi = off`

if none of these solution work may it's this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/683133)

Comment: Nope.. Does not work..   
`eirol@--------:~$ echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/toshiba::kbd_backlight/brightness 
[sudo] password for eirol: 
tee: '/sys/class/leds/toshiba::kbd_backlight/brightness': No such file or directory
2`

Comment: eirol@-----:~$ ls /sys/class/leds/
input3::capslock  input3::numlock  input3::scrolllock  phy0-led  


eirol@-----:~$

Comment: @EirolJohn i update my answer

Answer (score 0):

try with `Fn+Z`  it worked in my toshiba

Reference found here https://forum.manjaro.org/t/toshiba-backlight-keyboard/25235