# hp star wars laptop keyboard backlight control, & screen brightness

Tags: hp, backlight, keyboard-backlight

I've just installed 16.04 on a new HP star wars laptop (a reskin of an HP pavillion I believe), but xset led 3 doesn't turn on the keyboard backlight.

Also there is no brightness slider or other brightness control for the screen.

This is the laptop with a skylake i5 CPU.

How can I fix this?

Comment: for screen brightness check my previous answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/770100/464430

Comment: for keyboard backlight check also this link changing to hp folder http://askubuntu.com/a/780184/464430

Answer (score 1):

I chased around a few more links from the ones you gave Mohamed and found.....

I used the fix [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04) to add a 20-intel.conf file and I now have a brightness slider and working keyboard shortcuts.

I found the fn key works backwards - by default the magic functions work, pressing the fn key means you get Fx key - this is the way the keyboard legends are marked tho'.

so kekyboard backlight can be switched on & off OK.