# can't turn on backlit keyboard 18.10

Tags: keyboard-backlight

I seem to find very old threads and results when googling.

I have an Asus UX331UAL and my keyboard brightness worked fine when I used Manjaro KDE. Now when I have Ubuntu 18.10 they keystroke registers (I see the HUD pop up but with no possible changes). How can I fix this?

I tried "xset led 3" in the terminal, and "xset led on". nothing happens.

Comment: here is link recommend for your answer it can be useful : https://askubuntu.com/a/644420/881622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone!

Updating the kernel to 4.19 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the keyboard back light issue on a 2011 Macbook pro, I installed radeontool which solved the issue <kbd>F4</kbd> &<kbd>F5</kbd> now perform correctly.

```
sudo apt-get install radeontool
```