# Keyboard Lights

Tags: keyboard, xorg, login

I have a black keyboard with characters which are completely invisible until the keyboard light comes on... Which it doesn't. I've made a script to toggle the light:

```
#!/bin/bash
FLAGS=$(xset -q | awk 'NR==2' | awk '{ print $10 }')
if [ "$FLAGS" = 00000000 ] || [ "$FLAGS" = 00000002 ]; then
    xset led 3
else
    xset -led 3
fi
```

My problem is that I can't find where to put it to make it work at the login prompt (I think I am using GDM.) So every time I boot, I log in blind and I can only turn the lights on once logged in :(

So, questions!

xset is an X11 command? 
 Will it even run at the login prompt?
 I'm guessing it has to wait until X11 starts?

Where do I put it?

I've tried putting it in:
/etc/X11/Xsession.d
/etc/init.d

Neither seem to work.

Thanks!

Beth

Comment: This answer may be helpful http://askubuntu.com/a/577485/320386

Answer (score 0):

Wait, found it! Sry... :$

[How to light up back-lit keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13886/)

> for those who land here because they also want the keyboard to light up BEFORE the login screen:
>
> Finally found an answer, at least for Ubuntu 14.04
>
> as for how to get the keyboard to light up before the login screen:
>
> Edit ***/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf***
>
> ```
> sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
> ```
>
> Add the line:
>
> ```
> greeter-setup-script= xset led 3
> ```