# Allow mouse movement and/or keyboard to trigger keyboard backlight

Tags: keyboard, mouse, keyboard-backlight

Currently, in order to trigger my keyboard backlight, I'm required to press the dedicated backlight button. I know that the backlight is located at /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight. I'd like to change my settings so that three things will happen:

1. Mouse movement turns on keyboard backlight
2. Pressing any key turns on keyboard backlight
3. Backlight turns off after a set amount of time, let's say ten seconds.

This is how the keyboard worked on Windows 10 before installing Ubuntu, so I'm essentially trying to replicate the backlight settings from how they were before. I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04 and GNOME 3.36.8 on an Asus Q406D two-in-one notebook.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/13886/1438484). It is a different keyboard, but if that lets you control the backlight manually, that makes answering your question way easier.

Comment: Keyboard backlights are not usually configurable by software since there is not a standardized implementation. Generally it's not configurable by software at all unless the hardware manufacturer publishes software for this purpose.

Comment: somewhere, you have a device in /dev maybe. you need to find where the device is. then you can write a little daemon to turn them on and off. when you find it, update the question with the device listing.