# Keybord backlight not working in Toshiba Laptop

Tags: 22.04

My keybord backlight was working fine in Windows 10. I used to just use FN key with Z alphabet and the keyboard would jus turn on its lights; however, after installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 does not work anymore. I would be thankful if anyone could help me. I am used Toshiba laptop Z30-A-183

Comment: there are some suggested solutions in [this old hardware question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13886/how-to-light-up-back-lit-keyboard#18628) any help?